# Autohotkey: Merging/combining two scripts in one script (#if WinActive, 2 actions)

Tags: merge, autohotkey

I have 2 scripts I want to merge in one file, however when I put them together, only the first one gets executed:

**Script 1:**

```
#if WinActive("ahk_exe program.EXE")
#Persistent
Loop
{
WinWaitActive, Wizard
Send, !{F4}
}

Return
```

**Script 2:**

```
#if WinActive("ahk_exe program2.EXE")

#Persistent
Loop
{
    WinWait, ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96
    ; IfWinNotActive,  ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96, ,WinActivate, ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96
    ; WinWaitActive, ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96
    ; Sleep, 0
    ControlMove, RichEdit20W6, 20, 850, 750, 25   ;Adress box
    ControlMove, SysTreeView321, , , 800, 700
    ControlMove, TreeViewCFParent1, , , 1000, 700
    ControlMove, SysTreeView322, , , 800, 700
    ControlMove, TreeViewParent1, , , 760, 940
    WinMove, ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96, , 600, 50, 1000, 900 ; 900 width
}

Return
```

I tried removing or changing the location of "#Persistent", "Loop", "Return"..  or adding #if at the end of each script.. still only the first one gets executed..  Even when trying to #Include the first script in the second, the first only gets executed.  Maybe it needs "else" or something.. not sure..

Comment: Your problem is using a `loop` to wait for a window.  You never "break" from the first loop to let the second loop start.  You should set both up as a `settimer` function to run a check for an active window (say every 500 ms).

Comment: Thanks, can you edit the script as suggested?  I am new to this and not sure how to implement it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [#If directive](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) is only used for creating context-sensitive hotkeys and hotstrings.

If you use **WinWait** or **WinWaitActive** the script waits until the (first) window exists or becomes active and doesn't go any further to move the second window.

Without WinWait the CPU usage of the script is high.

The better solution in this case is [SetTimer](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm):

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, Close_Move_Windows, 500 
return

Close_Move_Windows: 
IfWinActive, Wizard
    WinClose
IfWinExist, ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96
{
    WinGetPos, X, Y, Width, Height, ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96
    If (X != 600 || Y != 50 || Width != 900 || Height != 1000) ; "!" means "NOT" and "||" means "OR"
    {
        ControlMove, RichEdit20W6, 20, 850, 750, 25   ;Adress box
        ControlMove, SysTreeView321, , , 800, 700
        ControlMove, TreeViewCFParent1, , , 1000, 700
        ControlMove, SysTreeView322, , , 800, 700
        ControlMove, TreeViewParent1, , , 760, 940
        WinMove, ahk_class bosa_sdm_Mso96,, 600, 50, 900, 1000 ; 900 width
    }
}   
Return
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working.. but what if two programs have the same ahk_class and I want to set the exe for each?

Comment: You can use [Multiple Criteria](https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm#multi) within the WinTitle parameter, e.g. `IfWinExist, ahk_class bosa_sdm_msword ahk_exe WINWORD.EXE`